# Detect combination key in JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, keypress

How do I detect the combination key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in a `JTextField`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a KeyListener detect key combinations (e.g., ALT + 1 + 1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851505/how-can-a-keylistener-detect-key-combinations-e-g-alt-1-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a special case since <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is a focus traversal key.  The focus subsystem normally consumes focus traversal keys, so you'll need to prevent that by calling

```
component.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
```

on your `JTextField`.  You'll then be able to detect the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination and handle it yourself.

See [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for an example program you can download and experiment with to see how it works.

Comment: +1, for turning off forcus traversal. -1, for suggesting a KeyListener. Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to use Key Binding. Read the section from the same tutorial on "How to Use Key Bindings".

Answer (score 2):

is this what you want?

```
javax.swing.JTextField textField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
textField.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
javax.swing.Action myAction = new javax.swing.AbstractAction()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    //Insert arbitrary code here
  }
};
textField.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, Event.SHIFT_MASK), "myCode");
textField.getActionMap().put("myCode", myAction);
```

Comment: not use KeyListener this is wrong way, Swing JComponents are designated to use KeyBinding, only KeyBindings can override built-in key-shortcuts, only KeyBindings wokrs as you set, only KeyBindings ignore when JComponents has Fosus, or doesn't ignore, as you set

Comment: I've modified my example to use key bindings instead

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is only/by default (only `KeyBinding` can change that) about moving `Focus` from one `JComponent` to another, I think that you have to look at [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) with detailed descriptions in the [FocusSubsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html), notice `Focus` came from Native OS and is by default `asynchronous`, most of time required delaying their actions/events wrapped into `invokeLater()`