# Robot keyPress not working in linux

Tags: java

I used Robot class several times but I had no issues with it in Windows. 
But this time I am using Fedora and if i try

`keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS)` its not working.

How to simulate pressing Windows key in linux(Fedora)?

P.S: I even tried `Event.META_MASK` but no luck

Comment: What does the Windows key on `Linux` do anyway?

Comment: It is my requirement @MadProgrammer .

Comment: What I'm curious about is if the key is actually recognised by the linux keyboard driver...

Comment: @MadProgrammer : usually it's denoted as `Meta`. It's generally an additional modifier key, like Ctrl/Alt/Shift, but with the advantage of practically and comparably low risk of conflicts in keybindings.

Comment: And that specific code indeed doesn't work, although that's the code for registered keypresses on the Windows key (and not `VK_META`). Confirmed on another distro.

Comment: I haven't got any solution yet. I am afraid that this thread is inattentive for a long time and may discarded. Does anyone have solution???

Answer (score -1):

Using an edited version of the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301775/get-key-combinations):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Sample implements KeyListener {
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample");

    public Sample() {
        panel.add("North", label);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        label.addKeyListener(this);
        pnl.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sample();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
        System.out.println(key.getExtendedKeyCode());
        System.out.println(key.getKeyCode());
        System.out.println(key.getModifiers());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

You can check the `KeyEvent` key code for any key with this program. For me (Fedora 19 x86_64, Oracle Java 1.7.0_40 x86_64) the *meta* key is indeed mapped to **524**, which according to the [constant values lookup table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS) is mapped to `VK_WINDOWS`

Now the problem is, when you try to press the key via `java.awt.Robot`:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class RobotTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot r = null;
        try {
            r = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        r.setAutoDelay(250);

        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);

    }

}
```

My system shortcut to run `konsole` wasn't triggered by pressing *meta+z* with `Robot`.

I guess AWT, or `Robot` itself is handling the *meta* key incorrectly somehow. Maybe Java is not yet up to standard of usage the *Windows* key in Linux - for example in Gnome Shell keyboard shortcuts.

I would personally try not to use it, or try a different framework, f.e. Eclipse SWT.

Trying to run the `RobotTest` with OpenJDK didn't yield any better results.

Comment: So you explained everything except the possible solution.
Thank you for that long post BUT i didn't got the solution.

Comment: You'll be better of using a different toolkit and/or a different OS, since the *current* java7 implementation of `Robot` doesn't actually simulate the key being pressed (on Fedora).

Answer (score -1):

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

In linux windows key is taken as ctrl + alt