# Substitute for the Robot Class on Fedora

Tags: java, linux, javafx, awtrobot

Although I find it a bit hacky to use the Robot class, it served my application well on Linux, Mac OSX and Windows. Now, I am trying to use it on Fedora, but the Robot Class is not working properly.

I use the Robot to press Enter or TAB in some situations, such like getting focus on the next ComboBox on selection of an item in the previous one.

**My question is:** is there any substitute for the Robot Class which is working on Fedora?

I am asking this question, because it has not received a proper answer here: [Robot keyPress not working in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912556/robot-keypress-not-working-in-linux)

Note: I am using JavaFX8.

Edit: As Eypros pointed out, the problem is Fedora specific.

Comment: `served my application well on Linux` but on `Fedora` it does not. Am I missing something here? Fedora is linux.

Comment: My bad, took the wrong conclusion. Thanks for pointing that out @Eypros, I will update my question appropriately.

Comment: If you look at the API it says: "Note that some platforms require special privileges or extensions to access low-level input control. If the current platform configuration does not allow input control, an AWTException will be thrown when trying to construct Robot objects. For example, X-Window systems will throw the exception if the XTEST 2.2 standard extension is not supported (or not enabled) by the X server.

Applications that use Robot for purposes other than self-testing should handle these error conditions gracefully." So check privileges or extensions to access low-level input control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX8 supports public constructors for [KeyEvents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#KeyEvent-javafx.event.EventType-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-javafx.scene.input.KeyCode-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-). I'm assuming you want to fire some button event. In that case, this should work:

```
KeyEvent enterKey = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,"","",KeyCode.ENTER,false,false,false,false);
Event.fireEvent(someButton, enterKey);
```

Comment: Great!! This solves a part of my problem, in which I used the Robot to press a button in a dialog. Thank you!