# Print key event

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this JavaFX code which prints which key is pressed.

```
package keyboardexample;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class KeyboardExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        final Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(new Key(KeyCode.A),
                new Key(KeyCode.S),
                new Key(KeyCode.D),
                new Key(KeyCode.F));

        final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(keyboard.createNode()));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Keyboard Example");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static final class Key {

        private final KeyCode keyCode;
        private final BooleanProperty pressedProperty;

        public Key(final KeyCode keyCode) {
            this.keyCode = keyCode;
            this.pressedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "pressed");
        }

        public KeyCode getKeyCode() {
            return keyCode;
        }

        public boolean isPressed() {
            return pressedProperty.get();
        }

        public void setPressed(final boolean value) {
            pressedProperty.set(value);
        }

        public Node createNode() {
            final StackPane keyNode = new StackPane();
            keyNode.setFocusTraversable(true);
            installEventHandler(keyNode);

            final Rectangle keyBackground = new Rectangle(50, 50);
            keyBackground.fillProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(pressedProperty)
                    .then(Color.RED)
                    .otherwise(Bindings.when(keyNode.focusedProperty())
                    .then(Color.LIGHTGRAY)
                    .otherwise(Color.WHITE)));
            keyBackground.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            keyBackground.setStrokeWidth(2);
            keyBackground.setArcWidth(12);
            keyBackground.setArcHeight(12);

            final Text keyLabel = new Text(keyCode.getName());
            keyLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));

            keyNode.getChildren().addAll(keyBackground, keyLabel);

            return keyNode;
        }

        private void installEventHandler(final Node keyNode) {
            // handler for enter key press / release events, other keys are
            // handled by the parent (keyboard) node handler
            final EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler =
                    new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        setPressed(keyEvent.getEventType()
                                == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED);

                        keyEvent.consume();
                    }
                }
            };

            keyNode.setOnKeyPressed(keyEventHandler);
            keyNode.setOnKeyReleased(keyEventHandler);
        }
    }

    private static final class Keyboard {

        private final Key[] keys;

        public Keyboard(final Key... keys) {
            this.keys = keys.clone();
        }

        public Node createNode() {
            final HBox keyboardNode = new HBox(6);
            keyboardNode.setPadding(new Insets(6));

            final List<Node> keyboardNodeChildren = keyboardNode.getChildren();
            for (final Key key : keys) {
                keyboardNodeChildren.add(key.createNode());
            }

            installEventHandler(keyboardNode);
            return keyboardNode;
        }

        private void installEventHandler(final Parent keyboardNode) {
            // handler for key pressed / released events not handled by
            // key nodes
            final EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler =
                    new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    final Key key = lookupKey(keyEvent.getCode());
                    if (key != null) {
                        key.setPressed(keyEvent.getEventType()
                                == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED);

                        keyEvent.consume();
                    }
                }
            };

            keyboardNode.setOnKeyPressed(keyEventHandler);
            keyboardNode.setOnKeyReleased(keyEventHandler);

            keyboardNode.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                    new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                public void handle(
                        final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    handleFocusTraversal(
                            keyboardNode,
                            keyEvent);
                }
            });
        }

        private Key lookupKey(final KeyCode keyCode) {
            for (final Key key : keys) {
                if (key.getKeyCode() == keyCode) {
                    return key;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static void handleFocusTraversal(final Parent traversalGroup,
                final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            final Node nextFocusedNode;
            switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
                case LEFT:
                    nextFocusedNode =
                            getPreviousNode(traversalGroup,
                            (Node) keyEvent.getTarget());
                    keyEvent.consume();
                    break;

                case RIGHT:
                    nextFocusedNode =
                            getNextNode(traversalGroup,
                            (Node) keyEvent.getTarget());
                    keyEvent.consume();
                    break;

                default:
                    return;
            }

            if (nextFocusedNode != null) {
                nextFocusedNode.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        private static Node getNextNode(final Parent parent,
                final Node node) {
            final Iterator<Node> childIterator =
                    parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().iterator();

            while (childIterator.hasNext()) {
                if (childIterator.next() == node) {
                    return childIterator.hasNext() ? childIterator.next()
                            : null;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        private static Node getPreviousNode(final Parent parent,
                final Node node) {
            final Iterator<Node> childIterator =
                    parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().iterator();
            Node lastNode = null;

            while (childIterator.hasNext()) {
                final Node currentNode = childIterator.next();
                if (currentNode == node) {
                    return lastNode;
                }

                lastNode = currentNode;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how I can print which key combinations are pressed. For example something like this: CTL + L, Alt + J, K and etc.

Comment: This thread may answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851505/how-can-a-keylistener-detect-key-combinations-e-g-alt-1-1

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [KeyEvent.isXXXDown](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#isAltDown%28%29) methods, for instance:

```
final EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler =
    new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.isAltDown()) {
                // do something
            }
        }
   };
```

Comment: I can print single character with this code `System.out.println(keyEvent.getText());` But I cannot print combination of characters.