# Detect the Windows key modifier

Tags: java, keyevent

How can I detect the `Windows key` modifier for `KeyEvent`? I have add the code:

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if ((e.getKeyCode() & KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            textField.setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

But the problem is, when I use the `Windows zoom` and try to exit from it using `Win + Escape`, if focus is in `TextField`, its content clears. I've tried filter by `e.getModifiersEx()`, but it returns `0`. The only way I've found is to detect whether `Windows` pressed or not, is to create `boolean` field and change it's value when `Windows` pressed/released.

So, is there any way to get the `Windows` key pressure state from `KeyEvent` for `ESCAPE released` event?

Comment: This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851505/how-can-a-keylistener-detect-key-combinations-e-g-alt-1-1.

Comment: Yes, I know about `KeyStrokes`, but is there any way to do that by `KeyListener` only?

Comment: It might be difficult. From the tutorial (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), it will send several events when a key combination is pressed. Have you ever tried `KeyEvent.getModifiers`?

Comment: of course, i've tried both `getModifiers` and `getMofidiersEx()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I used for myself:

```
AbstractAction escapeAction = AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
        setText("");
    }
}

textField.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
    @Override
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
        if (textField.getText() == null || textField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            textField.getActionMap().remove("escape");
            textField.getInputMap().remove(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0));
        } else {
            textField.getActionMap().put("escape", escapeAction);
            textField.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), escapeAction);
        }
    }
});
```