# How to add KeyListenet for shift+8(*) or for any two keys in java

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

I have a regular JButton.
I need to use shift+8 (*) for JButton.
How can I implement?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'll write here.
Have you tried any of these solutions:

[Swing's KeyListener and multiple keys pressed at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623995/swings-keylistener-and-multiple-keys-pressed-at-the-same-time)

[How can a KeyListener detect key combinations (e.g., ALT + 1 + 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851505/how-can-a-keylistener-detect-key-combinations-e-g-alt-1-1?rq=1)